# Connecting HTML Form to SQL Database

Tags: php, html, sql

I have created an HTML form on my website using the HTML widget on Elementor. The php code is in a file named config.php in my file manager. I am trying to connect the html submission data with a SQL Database, but I am having trouble obtaining a connection. Below is my HTML code and PHP code. I think where I am struggling the most is how to handle the html form knowing which file to send the data to for the database connection and data transfer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Tournament Registration</h1>
            <hr style=
            "background-color:black;
            margin:auto;">
            <form 
                action="/domains/XYZ.com/public_html/Forms/config.php"
                method="post">
            <div
                class="form-field">
                 <input 
                    style= 
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;
                    margin-top: 20px;"
                    type=text
                    class=text
                    name=firstname
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <input 
                    style= 
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;"
                    type=text
                    class=text
                    name=lastname
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div 
                class="form-field">
                <input 
                    style= 
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;"
                    type=email
                    class=text
                    name=email
                    placeholder="Email"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div 
                class="form-field">
                <input 
                    style=
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;"
                    type=text
                    class=text
                    name=phonenumber
                    placeholder="Phone Number"
                    required>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </div>
            <div 
                class="form-field">
                <input 
                  style= 
                  "width:250px;
                  padding:10px;"
                  type=text
                  class=text
                  name="handicap"
                  placeholder="Handicap"
                  required>
                  <br>
                  <br>
            </div>
            <div 
                class="form-field">
                <select
                  style=
                  "width:250px;
                  padding:10px;"
                  class=text
                  name="shirtsize"
                  size = 1
                  required>
                    <option
                        value="" 
                        selected>
                        Shirt Size
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="S">
                        S 
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="M">
                        M 
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="L"> 
                        L 
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="XL">
                        XL 
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="2XL">
                        2XL
                    </option>
                    <option
                        value="3XL">
                        3XL
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div
                class="form-field">
                <input
                    style=
                    "width:250px;
                    padding:10px;
                    margin-left:auto;"
                    type=submit
                    value=Register>
            </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$servename = "localhost";
$database = "u759373654_Forms";
$username = "u759373654_username";
$password = "password";

// Create Connection

$conn = 
new msqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check Connection

if  (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: ". msqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connection Successful";

$firstname = $_POST[firstname];
$lastname = $_POST[lastname];
$email = $_POST[email];
$phonenumber = $_POST[phonenumber];
$handicap = $_POST[handicaop];
$shirtsize = $_POST[shirtsize];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Registration Form (firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber, handicap, shirtsize) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$phonenumber', '$handicap', '$shirtsize')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Registration Successful";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Unless you have these constants defined this should give you an error: `$_POST[handicaop]`

Comment: What is `msqli_connect`? There is no such function. Same with `msqli_connect_error`

Comment: You need to delete this PHP code and start over. This time learn PDO and prepared statements. This code is unusable in the current form. Start here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Hey Dharman, thanks for the response and the information. My plan was to go back through and secure the code once I was able to establish a connection and have the information submitted to the database.  The mysqli_connect and mysqli_connect_error was taken directly from the Hostinger tutorial I am using on connecting to a database https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-php-to-mysql.

Comment: That's not how it works. You have to write secure code from the start else you need to write it twice.

Comment: 10-4 I appreciate the help. I'll go ahead a start over using the information you provided. Is there anyway you can comment on what I was doing wrong as far as connecting my HTML form to the database, other than the lack of security?

Comment: I did, please see my first 3 comments